# GridView row spacing fills screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-gridview

Im having a grid view that has blank space between two rows. I'm trying to remove the white space but without success. So can anyone tell me how can I remove the white spacing?

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/bg_chooser_grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is gridItem xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

The "important part of the adapter":

```
 gridImg = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_img);
 gridImg.setImageResource(data.get(position));
```

And here is how it looks:
[image]

Comment: do you have a custom layout to display images?. At first i mistook it for a staggered griview.

Comment: @Raghunandan question updated

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try This Code :- 

     <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
        </GridView>


and customGridAdapter xml view:-


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_border"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/home" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This image use in LinearLayout android:background="@drawable/grid_border"

[image]